# JFrame not found when importing

Tags: java, android, eclipse, swing

I'm learning Java and I have an issue when importing the JFrame class. This is my code;

```
public class GraphicsDemo extends JFrame {

}
```

In eclipse if I hover over JFrame and there is no option to import JFrame, I can only create a new JFrame class or fix project setup. I'm thinking its a problem with the java development kit I installed I'm not sure. I downloaded it straight from Oracle's website and the correct version but still I don't know what the issue could be.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Just wondering, does it work when you import it yourself? `import javax.swing.JFrame;`

Comment: Android does not support any of the `Swing` library...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probelm is that you probably put this in an andorid folder. 
Do this for it to work : New Java Project then make a new class in that class. then in the top line type jf and then click "Ctrl + Space" and then hit enter on JFrame it should auto-import what is needed. Also if you mean it doesnt work becasue nothing shows when you run it thats becasue the class has no constructor or main so do this.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class FrameExample extends JFrame {

    public FrameExample() {
        setSize(500,500);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FrameExample();
    }
}
```

When you run this it should work